# std::conditional - nested usage

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

Please, oh most wise C++ type_traits gurus, could someone explain why
this code fails with error shown - I am analysing latest C++-17
draft standard and cannot see why this should fail (with gcc-5.4.0 on Linux):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct a
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct b
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct c
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct abc
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct ab
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct ac
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct bc
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct d
{static
void f(void){}
};
struct e
{static
void f(void){}
};

#define C 3 

typedef
std::conditional
<(C<8), 
std::conditional
<C==7, abc,
std::conditional
<C==6, bc,
std::conditional
<C==5, ac,
std::conditional
<C==4, c,
std::conditional
<C==3, ab,
std::conditional
<C==2, b,
std::conditional
<C==1, a, d>>>>>>>,e
>::type T;

void f(void)
{ T::f();
}
```

The code does not compile:

```
$ g++ -I. -std=gnu++17 -g -O2 -mtune=native -fPIC -pipe -pthread 
-D_REENTRANT -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -fno-pretty-templates  -c /tmp/T.C 
-o /dev/null
/tmp/T.C: In function 'void f()':
/tmp/T.C:62:3: error: 'f' is not a member of 'T {aka 
std::conditional<false, abc, std::conditional<false, bc, 
std::conditional<false, ac, std::conditional<false, c, 
std::conditional<true, ab, std::conditional<false, b, 
std::conditional<false, a, d> > > > > > >}'
{ T::f();
        ^
```

My goal is to invoke a different class's f() function based
on every unique combination of the low-order 3 bits in the 'C' #define
(or enum member) .
I thought the above was meant to be what std::conditional was meant to do.
Note even though the condition for 'ab' is true, 'ab::f()' is not found. 
why ?

Comment: Could you have made the code any more unreadable?

Comment: @NeilButterworth : thanks for responding, but please stick to helpful comments - I thought I tried to make the code as SIMPLE and, hence as readable, as possible - how did I fail ?  The real code that fails is MUCH more complex.

Comment: That was a helpful comment - it was telling you that you need write much clearer code if you expect help here. You have heard of things like indentation and spacing, I hope?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
typedef
std::conditional
<(C<8), 
std::conditional
<C==7, abc,
std::conditional
<C==6, bc,
std::conditional
<C==5, ac,
std::conditional
<C==4, c,
std::conditional
<C==3, ab,
std::conditional
<C==2, b,
std::conditional
<C==1, a, d>::type>::type>::type>::type>::type>::type>::type,e
>::type T;
```

?

Comment: yes. that was the answer! Thanks! much quicker than embarking on a fifth re-read of the templates and type_traits chapters in  the manual ....

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `::type` on the other `std::conditional`s:

```
typedef std::conditional<C<8,  
    std::conditional<C==7, abc,
    std::conditional<C==6, bc,
    std::conditional<C==5, ac,
    std::conditional<C==4, c,
    std::conditional<C==3, ab,
    std::conditional<C==2, b,
    std::conditional<C==1, a, d>
    >::type
    >::type
    >::type
    >::type
    >::type
    >::type,e
>::type T;
```